# How to interpret this ASCII tab?

Tags: guitar, chords, notation, tablature

I'm a beginner guitar player and I was trying to play this tab. but I don't understand it. which strings to bar? Why the name of strings are not as normal and what does that 3/2 means ?

[image: The tab section]

Comment: This is the acual playing if that can help answering. http://picosong.com/VC7h/

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by the "SLIDEE" written down the side, but aside from that, I would personally play this with my thumb over the top fretting the 3rd fret on the low E string, then ring finger (third finger) on the 5th fret of the A string, pinky (fourth finger) on the 5th fret of D, and middle finger (second) on the 4th fret of G.

Most people don't fret with their thumb so you would instead reach up with your index (first finger) to fret the 3rd fret of the low E. All of your fretting fingers should be arched enough to prevent accidental muting of the B and high E strings.

Then with your picking hand you play each string one at a time from lowest (sounding) to highest as an arpeggio, and most likely let them ring.

Then let go with all fingers except the index finger, play the low E string again with the picking hand and slide the index finger down from the 3rd fret to the 2nd fret without lifting.

Comment: I would not play it with a bar (or barre) at all, BTW. The only place that would make sense would be on the A and D strings but it would be very hard for most people to barre that with their third or fourth finger.

Comment: Based on the audio file in the comment I think we've got it right. Do let the strings ring and don't use a slide. No idea why the string names are like that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, if the tuning is standard, that no barre is needed. Instead, play a Gmaj like you would with a barre, but only use the tip of the barre finger(index) on the bottom (fat)E. Then play each string in turn, bottom to top. Then slide the bottom down a fret. My tuner can't find the three notes S,L and I...

Hearing it, all strings are tuned down a tone, and it's played arpeggiated.